AWS boto3 can't create a bucket - Python
Iam facing an issue that I my code is not successfully to create bucket in AWS using boto3 python. Below my code
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

def create_bucket(bucket_name, region='us-east-1'):
    if region is None:
        s3.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name)
    else:
        location = { 'LocationConstraint': region }
        s3.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name,
                         CreateBucketConfiguration=location)

create_bucket('my-testing-bucket')

When I run, I got this error botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (IllegalLocationConstraintException) when calling the CreateBucket operation: The us-east-1 location constraint is incompatible for the region specific endpoint this request was sent to.. Will be happy to get your help. Thanks
I want to create a bucket in AWS S3 using boto3 python. But I got an error in my code

It's not directly addressed in the docs, but us-east-1 is not a valid location constrain, only the other regions are.  If you want to create a bucket in us-east-1, you need to leave the location constraint off as that's the default behavior.

There's a couple of issues:

When creating a bucket, the boto3 client needs to connect to the same region as where the bucket is being created. Therefore, you will need to pass a region_name when creating the S3 client.
The default value of the region parameter in your create_bucket() function will pass a value of 'us-east-1', so region will never be null

Here's some updated code:
import boto3

region = 'us-east-1'

s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name=region)

def create_bucket(bucket_name, region='us-east-1'):
    if region == 'us-east-1':
        s3.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name)
    else:
        location = { 'LocationConstraint': region }
        s3.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name,
                         CreateBucketConfiguration=location)

create_bucket('my-new-bucket')


Thanks John
I got the clue. So I think in my previous code is trying to change the region to us-east-1 (which is the default region if its null), so it's return an error. Now, I have updated my code look like this and it's work.

def create_bucket(bucket_name, region='us-west-1'):
    if region is None:
        s3_client = boto3.client('s3', region_name=region)
        s3.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name)
    else:
        s3_client = boto3.client('s3', region_name=region)
        location = {'LocationConstraint': region}
        s3_client.create_bucket(
            Bucket=bucket_name,
            CreateBucketConfiguration=location)

create_bucket("my-buckets-25")```

I think that if region is None will never trigger because def create_bucket(bucket_name, region='us-west-1') will always provide a default value.

Got it. Thanks John
